# php form to multiply 3 numbers where one is variable entered by user

Tags: php, forms, function, numbers

I have 4 variables

```
$daysperweek=7;
$hoursperday=24;
$minutesperhour=60;
$minutesperweek=($minutesperhour * $hoursperday) * $daysperweek=7;
```

I need to create the form with calculate button, so user can enter any number of $hoursperday and the function which will calculate the $minutesperweek

I have this formula

```
<?php
$mul = gmp_mul("60", "24") , "7";
echo gmp_strval($mul) . "\n";
?>
```

but not sure how to declare $hoursperday variable that can be any number entered by the user, and how to place everything in the form

Idealy I would get something like this: enter (form:number of hours per day) and PHP function will (submit button: calculate) number of minutes per week - echo result

Any hint would be great,

Thanks a lot,

Anton

Comment: why do you have an `=7` on the end of this line? `$minutesperweek=($minutesperhour * $hoursperday) * $daysperweek=7;` and why are you using `gmp_mul`? how big do you expect these numbers to get? and why the trailing `,"7";`? pretty sure that's a syntax error.

Comment: Are you trying to force the value to an int?  Surely you could use a $_POST['somevar'] and some simple validation, like is_int(), and maybe round(), floor(), or (int) typecast to deal w/ this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
<?php
 $daysperweek = 7;

if($_POST['calculate'])
{
 $hoursperday = intval($_POST['hoursperyday']);
 $minutesperweek = 60*$hoursperday*$daysperweek;
 echo "Minutes per week: ".$minutesperweek;
}
else
{
?>
<form method='post' action=''>
Hours per day: <input tpye='text' name='hoursperday' value=''>
<br />
<input type='submit' name='calculate' value='Calculate Minutes per week!'>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use a form to capture the hours, then PHP to do the calculation.

```
<?php

define("MINUTES_PER_HOUR", 60);
define("DAYS_PER_WEEK", 7);

$result = null;

if (isset($_POST["hpd"])) {
    $hpd = intval($_POST["hpd"]);
    $result = (int)MINUTES_PER_HOUR * (int)DAYS_PER_WEEK * $hpd;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method=POST>
    <label>Hours per Day: <input name="hpd" type="number" value=24></label>
    <button type=submit>Go</button>
</form>

<p class="result">
    <?php echo $result; ?>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```